# Close the servicenow incidents automatically. Is it possible?

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

Could anyone please tell me if there is a way to close the servicenow incidents automatically through automation process.

I am dealing with bulk p3 incidents daily. I want to figure out a way to reduce the manual effort.

Thank you
Pushpanth

Answer (score 1):

You could write JavaScript to find and close the Incidents, and run it from a scheduled job.

```
var grInc = new GlideRecord('incident');
// Add filtering logic here ...
grInc.addQuery( ...
grInc.addQuery( ...
grInc.query();
while (grInc.next()) {
    grInc.state = 7; // Closed
    grInc.update();
}
```

OR

If you do not want to write any JavaScript, you could do it using Flow Designer: (https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/paris-servicenow-platform/page/administer/flow-designer/concept/flow-designer.html)

Comment: If you could help me with some sample code that will be helpful for me.

Comment: The trick is knowing which incidents to close (and which ones to leave open). I do not know enough about your situation to answer that question. If you do not already know JavaScript, then I would strongly recommend that you use Flow Designer. It is easy to get yourself in trouble with ServiceNow JavaScript.

Comment: Okay.. I will try exploring the Flow designer and see how exactly we can do that. Thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
var gr = new GlideRecord('sc_task');

gr.addQuery('number','TASK0594091');
gr.query();

while (gr.next())
{
    gr.state = 10;
    gr.update();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).